# The need to turn a Parser into a Functor

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner in Haskell, and I'm trying to do this [exercise](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/10-applicative.pdf).

So I need to implements Functor Parser in order to implement Applicative Parser.

But I'm stuck on how to implement the Functor, even with the "first function hint" :(. Actually, I can't figure out what we are trying to achieve by using "fmap f Parser a".

Can someone explain it ?

Comment: Show us the definition of you parser type and of the attempts you've made at defining the instance yourself. But either way perhaps you should first read up a bit on functors... really, these aren't so difficult, and if you can't even figure out what to do with them then you'll have a hard time implementing the `Applicative` instance. [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) is always an easy start.

Comment: I've already read some stuff about functors (like in lyahfgg), and I can understand the use of fmap on easy(?) functors like lists, IO Monad, Maybe Monad. But here, I have to map a function over a function of type `String -> Maybe (a, String)`, and in that case, I can't understand the need to do this (expect that it is required to implement Applicative).

Comment: The functor instance of a parser is used to apply some transformation function to the final result of the parser, essentially changing a `Parser a` into `Parser b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to define

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
```

As usual, we start by pattern matching:

```
fmap f (Parser p) = _
```

The result has to be a parser, so let's apply the constructor:

```
fmap f (Parser p) = Parser _
```

Now we need a function in the hole, `String -> Maybe (b, String)`. So let's make one:

```
fmap f (Parser p) = Parser $ \s -> _
```

I'll let you try to finish this off.

Comment: I think you mean `String -> Maybe (b, String)`

Comment: Here's my implementation. But since I don't know what to expect from the functor, I don't if it OK : `instance Functor Parser where
    fmap g (Parser f) = Parser f' where
        f' s = case f s of
            Nothing -> Nothing
            Just (x, ss) -> Just (g x, ss)
`

Comment: @MaximeB., yes, that's exactly right. You can see what to expect from a `Functor` by reading the documentation for the class on Hackage.

Comment: @dfeuer, could you give a real example on why would I use fmap function over a Parser ?

Comment: @MaximeB., I think that would be an appropriate question to ask separately.